# Which type of grass to seed over a septic tank?

Tags: grass

I recently moved to a new house in Greece (Mediterranean climate). Unfortunately the septic tank is in the middle of the front yard and on top of it nothing is grown.
It is quite large and made by concrete, the layer of soil over the tank is very shallow, about 5 inches.

Which grass type is the most suitable for this case?
If i can't grow grass, what other options do i have?

Answer (score 1):

I feel you're asking the wrong question. I would seed mint over the septic tank rather than grass, and you can always beat it up so it will come back easily.

Comment: I had some hopes for some special types of "grass" that could work, like paspalum, zoysia or bermuda grass.. I need something that is resistant to heat that generates the concrete tank, mint can handle this?

Comment: yes, mint does well in a drought, and in a pot.

Comment: Creeping thyme may work well.

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about roots ruining tank a better solution is dig up the tank and puttva plastic sheet over it. Then seed it. Best use domestic Greece native forbe grass